# Check condition inside lambda expression using Stream API has SonarQube issues

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube, java-stream

So I have a code with ArrayList of Properties object.

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Properties {
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

I have to check if `list.get(index)` is not `null`, then if `list.get(index).getType()` is not `null`, then `list.get(index).getType()` equals `"something"`, then return the value.

Below is my code:

```
List<String> values = list.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(c -> c.getType() != null && c.getType().equals("something"))
    .map(Properties::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My problem is the second filter part has SonarQube issues. I have to implement it using static methods like it's done in map part and first filter.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your current approach. Can you point to the sonar rule which highlights this and what message does it pass on? You can't really convert `c -> c.getType.equals("something")` to a reference without a method, and that's what it might be pointing to. But do you really think it makes sense in your current context?

Comment: I assume that this might be due to the getters that are not present in the code but generated with annotations. Maybe SonarQube is not aware of those and assumes that `getType()` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know the rule of SonarQube highlighting any issue here. If there is an issue, it's definelty not related to the functionality but to the clarity.

The only improvement I see is to simplify the conditions within the second `filter` method:

```
List<String> values = list.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(c -> "something".equals(c.getType()))
    .map(Properties::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There is actual no need for null-check as long as you use a safe non-null string comparison which never yields in `NullPointerException`.

Comment: And `.filter(Objects::nonNull) .filter(c -> "something".equals(c.getType()))` can be expressed as `.filter(c -> c != null && "something".equals(c.getType()))`

Comment: @Holger: Do you prefer an inline condition or rather multiple calls of `filter` which I find more readable?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the condition. Just as I would never write `Objects.nonNull(x)` instead of `x != null`, I don’t use a stand-alone processing step when this simple condition is actually part of a compound condition. If the condition is complex enough that you would use the dedicated method anyway or when `Objects::nonNull` is the only condition, it would be a different thing. But with JDK8 and its default MaxInlineLevel setting, I’d avoid multiple steps in general, when the alternative still is maintainable Though, actually I prefer not to have `null` in lists in the first place

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> values = list.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(c -> Objects.equals("something", c.getType())
    .map(Properties::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```