# will objectList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::getField, Function.identity)) return null?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

i've got a list form DB, then i use the function above to translate it to a hashMap(already check out this list is not null or emptiy). but the sonarLint keeps telling me that the function above might return null, and it might caught NPE. And when i use enhanced for loop, the warning will disappear.

i can't find out why eventualy, hope you help me out of here.
Thanks a lot.

the code below that sonarLint says might return null:

> ```java
> return objectList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::getField, Function.identity()));
> ```

the code below that sonarLint says it's ok:

> ```java
>    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
>    for(Object obj : ObjectList) {
>        map.put(obj.getField(), obj);
>    }
>    return map;
> ```

Comment: I understand you're checking if the list is not null, but you don't check if each Object in the list is not null. Add a filter(Objects::nonNull) before your collect to ensure that each Object is not null

Comment: thanks for your reply, it helps me to learn the use of filter.
 i've done your way to ensure that each Object in list is not null, but the sonarLint still keeps telling me that the way i use to get hashmap might be null. maybe i did not make it very clear: the sonarLint is not saying the method i use might caught NPE, it tells me the method i use might return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't. The whole collection framework is build in ways to ensure that you don't end up with null where some empty collection could be provided instead.

So: the **collector** will not return null.

But: depending on your context, `obj.getField()` might return null. And there are conditions where collection methods throw NPEs for null **keys**.

Comment: " The whole collection framework is build in ways to ensure that you don't end up with null where some empty collection could be provided instead."got it. thanks for your patient answer. if collector will not return null, i prefer that sonarLint's warning is meaningless. thanks again~

Answer (score 0):

your code is good to handle not null, might be worth to visit the sonar rule, and also refer the [Check condition inside lambda expression using Stream API has SonarQube issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259739/check-condition-inside-lambda-expression-using-stream-api-has-sonarqube-issues)

Comment: the sonarLint notes that map.get(someKey) might thrown NPE(i use this map somewhere else), not the method i use above might thrown NPE. so when i confirm that the collector will not return null, i can say sonarLint's tips is nonsense. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @zihaoQ then, you should say that in the question. There is a fundamental difference between the collector returning `null` (in other words, the map being `null`) and the map’s `get` method returning `null`.